# Android Material Design OnSliderTouchListener slider not working

Tags: android, slider, material-design

I'm stuck on some simple code- probably missing some basics from a noob. I am building an app that had multiple seekbars in it and was working well. I decided to adopt MDC and tried to use sliders. I can't find too many posts that have helpful advice- can someone show me what changes are needed to avoid the error below- is it slider than is causing the null object reference?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slSlider"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with MainAcivity.java

```
package com.example.sliderapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.material.slider.Slider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    Slider.OnSliderTouchListener touchListener;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Slider slider = findViewById(R.id.slSlider);
        slider.addOnSliderTouchListener(touchListener);
        
        touchListener = new Slider.OnSliderTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {
                Log.d("***********", "Start");
            }

            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {
                Log.d("***********", "Stop");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

results in.......

```
2022-02-16 21:31:35.317 17028-17028/com.example.sliderapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sliderapplication, PID: 17028
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.material.slider.BaseOnSliderTouchListener.onStartTrackingTouch(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.onStartTrackingTouch(BaseSlider.java:2100)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.BaseSlider.onTouchEvent(BaseSlider.java:1711)
        at com.google.android.material.slider.Slider.onTouchEvent(Slider.java:40)
........
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - moved Listener outside of Create:

```
package com.example.sliderapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.material.slider.Slider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Slider.OnSliderTouchListener touchListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Slider slider = findViewById(R.id.slSlider);
        slider.addOnSliderTouchListener(touchListener);


    }

    private final Slider.OnSliderTouchListener touchListener =
            new Slider.OnSliderTouchListener() {
                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {
                    Log.d("***********", "Start");
                }

                @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(Slider slider) {
                    Log.d("***********", "Stop");
                }
            };

}
```

Comment: For anyone still having this problem, please **assign** listeners **after** initializing them. The OP assigned `touchListener` before it was initialized.